# PHP SoapServer handle() a gzip encoded request

Tags: php, soap, gzip

is anybody aware if PHPs builtin SoapServer is capable to handle GZIP encoded POST requests?

my application has to handle rather big soap requests which I like to optimize at the transport layer.

Comment: The SoapServer doesn't look like it's very configurable so you might be SOL.  Maybe rolling your own would be a better option (albeit considerable more work).  Alternatively, if SOAP supports blobs maybe zipping your data and putting it in a blob field would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: Just let the gzip/deflate be handled on a webserver level. This works transparently for the actual PHP app.